# How to disable click in navlinks in mat-tab-nav-bar in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

html:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
              <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.route" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
            </nav>
```

ts file :

```
public navLinks: { label: string, route: string }[] = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['tabs'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach 1

use `[disabled]="true"` attribute in html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.route" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive" [disabled]="true">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
</nav>
```

#### Approach 2

Specify the function which triggers in on click event like `(click)="onTabClick(routerLink1)` and then in component.ts follow it up with `tabLink.preventDefault();`

In html :

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
                  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.route" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive" #routerLink1 (click)="onTabClick(routerLink1)">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
                </nav>
```

In your component.ts :

```
onTabClick(tabLink: any): void {
    
    tabLink.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click behavior

    console.log('Tab clicked but not navigating.');
  }
```

Comment: the color is like disable but i still can click and navigate . I dont want to navigate in tab-route

Comment: use approach 2 preventdefault

Answer (score 1):

use `disabled` attribute like below

In navlinks array set a property disabled to true!

[docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api)

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.disabled ? null : link.route" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive" [disabled]="link.disabled">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: the color is like disable but i still can click and navigate . I dont want to navigate in tab-route

Comment: @ChristosSegkani updated my answer!